# How can I group items into collections stored as dictionary values?

Tags: python

So this is my code right now,

```
def course_rolls(records):
    """Returns course code as a key and then the
    student id as the value of the key"""
    course_roll_dict = {}
    for (course, student) in records:
        course_code = course[0]
        student_id = student[0]
        course_roll_dict.update({course_code:{student_id}})
```

and my output is

```
{'ENG002': {2721815},
 'FCOM02': {2113869},
 'ECO001': {2721815},
 'MTH001': {2923516},
 'ENG001': {2113869},
 'PHY001': {2949099},
 'GEL001': {2113869},
 'INF001': {2286481},
 'FCOM03': {2923516}}
```

but that is not the right output I want, I need to to be

```
{'ECO001': {2923516, 2721815},
 'ENG002': {2721815},
 'FCOM03': {2923516},
 'GEL001': {2113869},
 'FCOM02': {2113869},
 'PHY001': {2949099},
 'ENG001': {2923516, 2113869},
 'MTH001': {2923516},
 'INF001': {2286481}}
```

I just don't know how to give a key 2 values because there is two of the same key but two different values (or student ID's you could say). I'm for looping through text file. If I print out the course code and student ID, I get this:

```
ENG002 2721815
FCOM02 2113869
ECO001 2923516
MTH001 2923516
ECO001 2721815
ENG001 2923516
PHY001 2949099
GEL001 2113869
INF001 2286481
ENG001 2113869
FCOM03 2923516
```

Comment: In other words you're trying to group the elemens with the same key ?

Comment: Yeah, in other words

Comment: Make the dict value a list (or tuple, or set, etc.) instead of a single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries have the exact function you need - it's `setdefault`.  Change the last line of your code to this:

`course_roll_dict.setdefault(course_code, set()).add(student_id)`

Here's what this weird-looking line of code does. `setdefault` attempts to find the key `course_code` in the dictionary. If the key isn't there, it adds the key to the dictionary and uses the second argument (an empty set) as the value, which at also returns.  If the key is there, it just returns the value.  In either case, the returned value is the set of students processed so far.  Then you just add the new student to it.

You might also take a look at the class `defaultdict` in the standard library.

Comment: If it works for you please accept the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using `update` where you should use `add`:

This is what you have:

```
In [11]: my_dict = {"a": set((1,)), "b": set((2,))}

In [12]: my_dict.update({"a":set((3,))})

In [13]: my_dict
Out[13]: {'a': {3}, 'b': {2}}
```

This is what you want:

```
In [14]: my_dict = {"a": set((1,)), "b": set((2,))}

In [15]: my_dict["a"].add(3)

In [16]: my_dict
Out[16]: {'a': {1, 3}, 'b': {2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `groupby` from `itertools` module in order to solve your question, like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("my_file", 'r') as f:
    data = [k.split() for k in f.read().splitlines()]

course_roll_dict = {}

for k,v in groupby(sorted(data), lambda x: x[0]):
    course_roll_dict[k] = set(j[1] for j in v)

print(course_roll_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'ENG001': {'2113869', '2923516'}, 'FCOM03': {'2923516'}, 'INF001': {'2286481'}, 'ECO001': {'2721815', '2923516'}, 'ENG002': {'2721815'}, 'GEL001': {'2113869'}, 'FCOM02': {'2113869'}, 'PHY001': {'2949099'}, 'MTH001': {'2923516'}}
```